# Counting object on image algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, pattern-matching

I got school task again. This time, my teacher gave me task to create algorithm to count how many ducks on picture.

The picture is similar to this one:

[image]

I think I should use pattern recognition for searching how many ducks on it. But I don't know which pattern match for each duck.

Comment: Your teacher should have told you how to complete this task during the lessons. If you've got no clue, you probably should have been paying more attention! If you've got a specific programming question, please edit the question so that it asks that question. Otherwise, perhaps you should be asking your teacher.

Comment: The teacher didn`t give any clue. I have to fid out by myself. I think I should use pattern recognition. But I don`t know which part of image can be pattern for each duck. I don`t need source code. just algorithm or maybe pseudo code.

Comment: `http://www.DuckOverflow.com/`

Comment: Frankly, it doesn't look like a homework assignment, too complicated IMHO.

Comment: It's a very interesting homework assignment, although I agree that it is complicated!

Comment: Edge detection, finding all the local maxima of approximately-upside-down-U-shaped curves, and verifying the color just below the peak is yellow (not red) will pick out all the tops of their heads and will ignore the beaks and eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

Hough transform for circles:

- Initialize an accumulator array indexed by (x,y,radius)
- For each pixel:

  - calculate an edge (e.g. Sobel operator will provide both magnitude and direction), if magnitude exceeds some threshold then:

    - increment every accumulator for which this edge could possibly lend evidence (only the (x,y) in the direction of the edge, only radii between min_duck_radius and max_duck_radius)
- Now smooth and threshold the accumulator array, and the coordinates of highest accumulators show you where the heads are.  The threshold may leap out at you if you histogram the values in the accumulators (there may be a clear difference between "lots of evidence" and "noise").

So that's very terse, but it can get you started.

Answer (score 6):

I think that you can solve this problem by segmenting the ducks' beaks and counting the number of [connected components](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/label.htm) in the binary image.

To segment the ducks' beaks, first convert the image to [HSV color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and then perform a binarization using the hue component. Note that the ducks' beaks hue are different from other parts of the image.

Comment: I think this might have the same problem as my SIFT idea - what about the duck facing backwards? No beaks :/

Comment: That's correct. You only will get an approximate number with this method.

Comment: I guess an exact method is very hard if not impossible to find for this problem. Your method has an advantage against SIFT in a way that it is much simpler to implement, while giving an equally good approximation :)

Answer (score 2):

It might be just because I'm working with SIFT right now, but to me it looks like it could be good for your problem.

It is an algorithm that matches the same object on two different pictures, where the objects can have different orientations, scales and be viewed from different perspectives on the two pictures. It can also work when an object is partially hidden (as your ducks are) by another object.

I'd suggest finding a good clear picture of a rubber ducky ( :D ) and then use some SIFT implementation ([VLFeat - C library with SIFT but no visualization](http://www.vlfeat.org/),  [SIFT++ - based on VLFeat, but in C++](http://www.vlfeat.org/~vedaldi/code/siftpp.html) , [Rob Hess in C with OpenCV](http://blogs.oregonstate.edu/hess/code/sift/)...).

You should bear in mind that matching with SIFT (and anything else) is not perfect - so you might not get the *exact* number of rubber duckies in the picture.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. But i think my image will be hardly detected if using SIFT. Since there is duck that face bakward.

Comment: hm, that's true... but since the SIFT is (to a certain extent) invariant under perspective changes, it might be enough to use a few (2-3) learning pics (duck forward, backward, maybe from the side). and also, as I already mentioned, an universal and perfect method that would recognize any object in any position/orientation doesn't exist

Comment: How about first you use SIFT to recognise the forward and side facing ducks? Once you get those, blank out those areas (fill their bounding box with 255 or something). Then use SIFT to get the back-facing duck, which is basically being able to recognize a yellow ball shape. The links given in the answer are great, here's another one just in case (using OpenCV): http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/implementing-sift-in-opencv/